# Dynamically Loaded JS not available until after function completes

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have a function that loads jQuery using a load function. After it loads jQuery, in the next lines I try and call jQuery features, but they don't work.  If I reload the function it works.  I have tried using setTimeOut, callback function, and reloading the same function twice in my calling function, but can't get jQuery to be read the first time.

I am working on a platform (iNotes) that doesn't allow me to directly access the header, body, etc.  I have to do it programmatically.  I do not have access to onload, nor to add the .js files, other than through javascript.

I would like to load jQuery (and jQuery-ui) through the function, and then use the jQuery methods immediately afterwards.

alertTwo() is called from a menu item.

```
function alertTwo(){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
      chk4_jQuery();
      iPage();
  },0);
}

 function chk4_jQuery() {
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'    ) {
         loadJQ( function(){console.log('finallydone')});
    }else{
        // alert('Found jQuery');
    }
}

function loadJQ(finalCallback) {
    function load1() {
        loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js ', function(){
            console.log('jQuery loaded');
            load2();
        }, 'script');
    }
    function load2() {
        loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js', function(){
            console.log('Jquery UI loaded');
            load3();
        },'script');
    }
    function load3() {
        loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css',function(){
            console.log('css loaded');
            finalCallback();
        },'stylesheet');
    }
    load1();
}

function iPage(){
    var page = location.protocol.concat("//").concat(window.location.hostname) +  "/testPage.html";
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
               .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
               .dialog({
                   autoOpen: false,
                   modal: true,
                   height: 625,
                   width: 500,
                   title: "Some title"
               });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    }
```

In Chrome sources tab of developer's tools, I watch the breakpoints at these functions, and I see it go to loading the jQuery libs, then it gets to the iPage() function and errors out at

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
```

[image]

When I run the function again, it recognizes the jQuery variables and runs.

Anyone know how I can get it to work on the first try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke `iPage` as a callback.

```js
function alertTwo() {
  chk4_jQuery(); //Invoke `chk4_jQuery` function
}

function chk4_jQuery() {
  loadJQ(iPage); //Invoke `loadJQ` function and pass `iPage` function as argument
}
}

function loadJQ(finalCallback) { // `finalCallback` is nothing but `iPage`
  function load1() {
    loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js ', function() {
      console.log('jQuery loaded');
      load2();
    }, 'script');
  }

  function load2() {
    loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js', function() {
      console.log('Jquery UI loaded');
      load3();
    }, 'script');
  }

  function load3() {
    loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', function() {
      console.log('css loaded');
      finalCallback(); //`iPage` is invoked when all other scripts are loaded
    }, 'stylesheet');
  }
  load1();
}

function iPage() {
  var page = location.protocol.concat("//").concat(window.location.hostname) + "/testPage.html";
  var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
    .dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      height: 625,
      width: 500,
      title: "Some title"
    });
  $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rayon! Works like a charm. Can you explain to me or lead me in the right direction on what to review on why that made the difference, I obviously don't understand why callback was able to see the newly loaded script, but calling it programatically didn't.

Comment: @carlo, Go through the comments :)